# variable in static methods inside static class

Tags: c#, .net, oop, c#-4.0, static

please consider this code :

```
1)public static class MyClass
2){
3)    public static DateTime MyMethod(DateTime dt)
4)    {
5)         DateTime temp = new DateTime();
6)         temp = dt.AddDays(1);
7)         return temp;
8)    }
9)}
```

Does `temp` variable has instance per any calls to `MyMethod`? or because it is in a static method inside static class just one instance of `temp` variable allocate in memory?

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`temp` is neither a static nor an instance variable, it is a *local* variable. It absolutely does not matter whether the method in which it is declared is static or not: the variable's scope starts at the point of its declaration, and ends at the closing curly brace `}` of the scope in which it is declared. Each executing thread that goes through `MyMethod` gets its own copy of `temp`, which is invisible anywhere outside the variable's scope.

Comment: thanks dear friend.you mean if I place `SqlConnection` inside that method and open and close it that connection would open and close within each thread and every thread does not affect connection for other thread?

Comment: @Kerezo Yes, that is absolutely correct: each executing thread gets its own variable, no matter how many threads get at it concurrently.

Answer (score 4):

> Does temp variable has instance per any calls to MyMethod?

If you mean "does each call to `MyMethod` get a separate `temp` variable?" then the answer is yes.

The fact that it's a static method in a static class is irrelevant - it's a local variable, so you get a "new" local variable on each call.

Comment: you said `The fact that it's a static method in a static class is irrelevant` but in extension methods we do this

Comment: @Kerezo: What do you mean by "we do this"? Even in extension methods, local variables are still local variables...

Answer (score 0):

`temp` has one instance per call.

BTW I'm missing possibility to define static local variables in static methods as in C++.

Answer (score 0):

The temp variable, even in a static method, has to be declared a static, otherwise it is just created locally in that instance, then blown away when the method call ends.